# Create personal EventEmitter class

Tags: javascript, html, events, listener, eventemitter

I need to create an `EventEmitter` class with `constructor()` and `on(eventName, callback)` methods. Also have to make `Movie` a subclass of `EventEmitter` and use the inherited methods to publish `play` event when the method is called. I don't know how to create subclasses because I can't find examples using `class`.

After this I need to create a `Logger` class with `constructor()` and `log(info)` methods.

I need to do this:

```
terminator.on('play', () => logger.log('play'));
terminator.play(); // output: The 'play' event has been emitted
```

This is what I have until now:

```
class Movie{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    play(){
        //not important I think
    }

class Logger{
    constructor(){ 
        //not sure          
    }

    log(info){
        console.log("The '" + info +"' event has been emitted");
    }
}

class EventEmitter{
    constructor(){
        //not sure
    }       
    on(eventName, callback) {
        //idk
    }
}
```

Comment: Subclassing is `class Movie extends EventEmitter`. Look at the source of an event emitter like [nanobus](https://github.com/choojs/nanobus) to see how it’s done.

Comment: Happy Birthday! I'd be glad to tell about subclassing in ES6 way, with `extends` keyword, but honestly you can find it in the internet on your own, and the most important, it will not give you the understanding of how classes and subclasses actually work in JS.  [I'd suggest you a little reading](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes), it may take time, but will give you 1000x more power!